# Запуск файла с атрибутом ReadOnly

Tags: c#

Открываю из программы картинку в стандартном "Просмотр фотографий Windows" таким образом:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

proc.StartInfo.FileName = "1.jpg";

proc.Start();
```

Как программно запретить удаление картинки после её открытия?

Comment: Эээ, никак? Юзер на своей машине царь и бог.

Comment: Мне нужно предотвратить именно случайное удаление. К примеру если картинка открыта, пользователь может удалить её случайным нажатием delete. С этим и нужно справиться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно следом за `proc.Start();` выполнить [`File.Open`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/y973b725(v=vs.110).aspx).
Тогда файл не будет удален, так как его будет держать программа.

Однако, если пользователь на ПК админ, то он может спокойно его чем-нибудь разблокировать и удалить.

Comment: К сожалению, данный способ не сработал. Файл теперь нельзя изменять, но он всё также удаляется.

Comment: @dantt3: А вы пробовали `FileShare.Read`?

Comment: @VladD: Да. Эффекта увы нет

Comment: @dantt3: Странно. А вы не закрываете файл раньше времени? Может быть, ваше приложение завершается сразу после запуска просмотрщика?

Comment: @VladD: И правда, я слепой, забыл поток вынести. Спасибо большое

Comment: @dantt3: Пожалуйста! Хорошо, что всё получилось.